# Laravel Multiple file upload 5.6

Tags: laravel

Problem is my storing file directory is not working at all. If i could save Folders Direction i can show all files of folder.

**create.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['materials.store'], 'files' => true]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Файлаа энд хуулна уу') !!}
    {!! Form::file('attachments[]', ['roles' => 'form', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
    {!! Form::token() !!}
</div>
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])  !!}
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**materialscontroller@create**

```
dd($request,$files);
```

**config/app.php**

```
'fileDestinationPath' => 'uploads',
'allowedFileTypes' => 'jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,pdf',
'maxFileSize' => 1000000*2,
```

**Result is**

```
"_token" => "9Oxhj6WrzJGAl3Dw8LV9cw6QvW7nT5PhittIiJL8"
"title" => "China"
"description" => "Deleniti nobis earum voluptatem facere quis eiusmod occaecat nostrum commodo soluta sit beatae nesciunt quia quasi"
```

**Its show.blade.php thats how i print**

```
<h1><b>Хэлтэс : </b> {{ $material->title }}</h1><hr> 
<p class="lead"><b>Агуулга : </b>{{ $material->description }}</p><hr>
@foreach($files as $file)
<a href="http://localhost/QuizApp/resources/app/{{ $file }}">Файл татах</br></a>
@endforeach
```

**MaterialsController**

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath.$fileName.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(),file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
}
    if($uploaded){
        Material::create([
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'filename' => $date,
        ]);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It almost works sir. I just cant save direction of folder . if i save direction of folder i can show all of files of that folder.

Comment: Can we see the code storing these files?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy edited sir take a look please.

Comment: What is the value of `$destinationPath`? if it's `uploads` then you're missing a directory separator (`/`)

Comment: `$destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$date.'/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Model` check your `migrations` then check `destinationPath`. I think your code is fine. Your `Model` is not working as good. I guess